# Select elements from list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a the following list:

```
list = {
        {{0,1112},{1600,1110}}, {{0,693},{600,691}}, {{0,134},{1600,132}}, 
        {{1,188},{600,188}}, {{0,413},{1600,411}}, {{0,49},{600, 49}}
       }
```

I want to select all elements where `list[[#, 2, 1]] == 600`.

The resulting list should be:

```
{ {{0,693},{600,691}}, {{1,188},{600,188}}, {{0,49},{600,49}} }
```

I tried the following:

```
Select[list, list[[#, 2, 1]] == 600 &]
```

but I get errors:

> Part::pkspec1: The expression {{0,1112},{1600,1110}} cannot be used as
>   a part specification. ...

Comment: `Select[list, #[[2,1]]==600&]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cases[list, x : {_, {600, _}} :> x]
```

> {{{0, 693}, {600, 691}}, {{1, 188}, {600, 188}}, {{0, 49}, {600, 49}}}

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably go for @tomd's `Select` or @eldo's `Cases`, to be honest. But for completeness I thought I should add `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, #[[2, 1]] == 600 & /@ #] & @ list
```

(Edit: Or as @JM points out, a cleaner implementation is

```
Pick[#, #[[All, 2, 1]], 600] & @ list
```

)

Or you could do something like

```
If[#[[2, 1]] == 600, #, Nothing] & /@ list
```

(because who knows, someday you might need it). Both of which give

> {{{0, 693}, {600, 691}}, {{1, 188}, {600, 188}}, {{0, 49}, {600, 49}}}

Comment: Alternatively: `Pick[#, #[[All, 2, 1]], 600] & @ list`